# Find the Perforce Label a workspace is synced to

Tags: perforce

I have a Perforce workspace which is synced with a p4 label specification. How do I find out which label has been synced here in my workspace.

Comment: Originally posted here http://www.scmgalaxy.com/forum/18-perforce/323-find-perforce-label-info-from-workspace.html#325. Incidentally, it looks like you got a completely reasonable answer on that site.

Comment: I can't see how this information would be useful.  Perhaps you could explain why you need to know this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't.

If you are trying to do this then I would imagine you are approaching something wrong.  You should really be syncing to Changelists or if syncing to Labels then only briefly.